# How to convert a byte array to a string?

Tags: java, arrays

How do I convert a byte array to a string? Is this the correct syntax?

```
byteArray.toString();
```

Comment: Have you tried it? Was there a problem?

Comment: what does the compiler say? "Computer Says No!"???

Comment: @ Mitch Wheat i am getting different anwsers for bytearray.toString()    and     public void convertByteArrayToString() {

        byte[] byteArray = new byte[] {87, 79, 87, 46, 46, 46};

        String value = new String(byteArray);

        System.out.println(value);
    }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Best way to convert bytearray to String is

```
public void convertByteArrayToString(Charset encoding) {

        byte[] byteArray = new byte[] {87, 79, 87, 46, 46, 46};

        String value = new String(byteArray, encoding);

        System.out.println(value);
    }
```

Comment: String(byte[]) uses the system's default encoding. You should use String(byte[], String) to specify an encoding, which depends on what your encoding your bytes are in.

Comment: @Nick i am getting an error    String value = new String(byteArray, "text/xml; charset=utf-8"); as unsupported encoding exception

Comment: @Nick also tried String value = new String(byteArray, "charset=utf-8");

Comment: It should be a string such as `UTF-8`. See http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html for some standard charsets.

Answer (score 3):

You need to supply an encoding, otherwise you get the system default encoding, essentially a random value.

```
String value = new String(byteArray, encoding);
```